# How to get Token 2022 Program metadata?

Tags: metaplex, metadata, umi

Everything works for tokens with Token Program (TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA).

```
import * as solWeb3 from '@solana/web3.js';
import { Metaplex } from '@metaplex-foundation/js';

const connection = new solWeb3.Connection(solWeb3.clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'));
const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection);

const mint = new solWeb3.PublicKey('6Jrb7B3qk1mKo8hNgZYs4HDKCuzJXtPn2gV4nQz6KkCh');
const metadata = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({ mintAddress: mint });
```

But with Token 2022 Program (TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb) I get error:

```
AccountNotFoundError: The account of type [Metadata] was not found at the provided address [8zYwrayHFXcTrVYn1R6LW1vS8Q83u9L7RQt5MsTY6gHb]
```

I'm tried use Umi follow the advice from this thread: [How to get metaplex token metadata for SPL Token 2022?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9111/how-to-get-metaplex-token-metadata-for-spl-token-2022)

```
 import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults';
 import { publicKey } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi';

 const umi = createUmi('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com');
 umi.programs.bind('splToken', 'splToken2022');

 const asset = await fetchDigitalAsset(umi, publicKey('6Jrb7B3qk1mKo8hNgZYs4HDKCuzJXtPn2gV4nQz6KkCh'));
```

But got same error

Answer (score 3):

I've used the `getTokenMetadata` method from the `@solana/spl-token` package to get this info.

```
// Retrieve and log the metadata state
const metadata = await getTokenMetadata(
  connection, // Connection instance
  mint, // PubKey of the Mint Account
  'confirmed', // Commitment, can use undefined to use default
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
)
```

### Edit

In your case, as per your comment, you can't find it for `6Jrb7B3qk1mKo8hNgZYs4HDKCuzJXtPn2gV4nQz6KkCh` on Mainnet.

The snippet below uses the `getMint` and `getExtensionTypes` methods from `@solana/spl-token` to fetch the mint and display all the extension types it has enabled:

```
const conn = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'))
const mint = await getMint(
  conn,
  new PublicKey('6Jrb7B3qk1mKo8hNgZYs4HDKCuzJXtPn2gV4nQz6KkCh'),
  'confirmed',
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
)

const types = getExtensionTypes(mint.tlvData)
console.log(`Extension Types`, types.map((t) => ExtensionType[t]))
```

When running the above, it returns an empty array which indicates you didn't enable the metadata pointer extension.

My suggestion is to try minting a new token using [this tutorial](https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/metadata-pointer) and make sure it works as expected.

Also, it's recommended to test these things on `devnet` before creating them on `mainnet`.

Comment: I tried this method. It returns **null**

`package: "@solana/spl-token": "^0.3.11"`

`const connection = new solWeb3.Connection(solWeb3.clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'));`

`const mint = new solWeb3.PublicKey('6Jrb7B3qk1mKo8hNgZYs4HDKCuzJXtPn2gV4nQz6KkCh');`

`const metadata = await getTokenMetadata(connection, mint)`

Comment: It looks like the token did not get initialized properly, it's missing the MetadataPointer extension. Just updated my answer with some code that checks this.

Comment: If I can't get the metadata on mainnet how then does solscan.io display the metadata correctly?
https://solscan.io/token/5q9ReGYiM6hJwLpWDYDMazDSVX6rkwmaVFKvcBsDHEii#metadata
And did it in 2 ways: using metaplex and from URI (https://bafkreihbhscshxohriccvbrb2ozcyiagayoy35k7m3ai2a75xuzwew4eee.ipfs.nftstorage.link)
Maybe there is a way to get URI and retrieve metadata through a request?

Comment: @bossikkk I'm not suggesting this is not possible on mainnet, but it looks like you didn't properly initialize your token, it doesn't have a metadata extension.

I suggest you start experimenting (on devnet) with how this works, using my code to figure out if you created it with the right extensions.

 Once that's good, you can mint it on mainnet.